Update on tree table library
I am editing this function onBodyScroll(event) and my selected language from local storage.
You can choose an other way by direction value.
This is path to the file to edit node_modules/primeng/fesm2022/primeng-treetable.mjs.
This is my code use for this solution in function
onBodyScroll(event) {
    if (this.preventBodyScrollPropagation) {
        this.preventBodyScrollPropagation = false;
        return;
    }

    if (this.scrollHeaderViewChild && this.scrollHeaderViewChild.nativeElement) {
        let lang = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lang'))['code'] || 'en'
        if (lang == 'ar') {
            this.scrollHeaderBoxViewChild.nativeElement.style.marginLeft = 'unset'
            this.scrollHeaderBoxViewChild.nativeElement.style.marginRight = event.target.scrollLeft + 'px';
        } else {
            this.scrollHeaderBoxViewChild.nativeElement.style.marginRight = 'unset'
            this.scrollHeaderBoxViewChild.nativeElement.style.marginLeft = -1 * event.target.scrollLeft + 'px';
        }
    }

    if (this.scrollFooterViewChild && this.scrollFooterViewChild.nativeElement) {
        this.scrollFooterBoxViewChild.nativeElement.style.marginLeft = -1 * event.target.scrollLeft + 'px';
    }

    if (this.frozenSiblingBody) {
        this.frozenSiblingBody.scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
    }
}

